# Do EARs deployed on one instace of WAS share the same heap space

Tags: websphere, heap-memory, shared-memory, java-memory-model

When a wesbpher application server is running. it basically is running one JVM. Now if I deploy two EAR projects on the WAS, do these two EARS share the same JVM. Yes they do I guess.

But then my question becomes do these two EARs also share the same heap space? My guess is no, but how is that possible? One jVM will provide only one heap,right?

For the purpose of simplification, let us say there is just one WAS....no nodes and clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the two EARs running in the same Application Server share the same heap space. As you say, because they share the same JVM.

Comment: Thanks. But does it not cause problems? For example, EAR#1 may create an object called Person and EAR#2 may also create an object called Person (i.e both EARS contain a Person.class). I know both will have their own object id, so they are uniquley identified in the heap. But will there be no problems because of the shared heap? Just curious.

Comment: No, they don't share objects on the heap. I don't know the implementation details, but each has its own space in that heap.